# How to return values only after observing LiveData in Android [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, android-livedata

I have been facing this issue for quite sometime and would like to know a better approach to solve this problem. If you are aware of anything about how to solve it then please let me know.

I am building a project which takes data from an API and then following MVVM architecture I take the Retrofit instance to Repository, and then to ViewModel and further observe it from my fragment.

Now what I am working on currently is Login feature. I will send a number to the API and in response I will receive if the number is registered or not. If it is registered then I would move to the next screen.

Now the problem is that using one of the function in ViewModel I send that number to the API to get the response. And using a variable I observe that response.

Now I create a function which checks if the response was true or false and based on that I am using the logic to move to the next screen, but the issue is the returned value from the function. As LiveData works asynchronously in background it takes some time to return the value and in meantime the function returns the initial value which is false.

Function to verify response

```
    private fun checkNumber(): Boolean {
        var valid = false
        authRiderViewModel.response.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Timber.d("Response: $it")
            if (it.success == true) {
                valid = true
            }
        })
        Timber.d("Boolean: $valid")
        return valid
    }
```

Moving to next screen code:

```
binding.btnContinue.setOnClickListener {
            val number = binding.etMobileNumber.text.toString().toLong()
            Timber.d("Number: $number")
            authRiderViewModel.authDriver(number)

            if (checkNumber()) {
                val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToOtpFragment()
                findNavController().navigate(action)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Number not registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
```

So in case I received the true response from the server even then I would not move to the next screen because the initial value I received is false. I have spent few hours trying to fix it and any help would be appreciated. If you need any code let me know in comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have *four* distinct states:

- The server returned a positive response
- The server returned a negative response
- The server failed (e.g., returned a 500, timed out)
- You are waiting on the server

You are attempting to model that with two states: `true` and `false`. This will not work.

Instead, model it with four states. One approach is called "loading-content-error" and uses a `sealed class` to represent those states:

```kotlin
sealed class LoginState {
  object Loading : LoginState()
  data class Content(val isSuccess: Boolean) : LoginState()
  object Error : LoginState()
}
```

Your `LiveData` (or your `StateFlow`, once you migrate to coroutines) would be a `LiveData<LoginState>`. Your observer can then use a `when` to handle `Loading`, `Content`, and `Error` as needed, such as:

- For `Loading`, display a progress indicator
- For `Content`, do whatever you are doing now with your boolean
- For `Error`, display an error message

Comment: Seems reasonable, Thanks I would try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, **live data** observation is an **asynchronous** operation. You have to code accordingly.

Just calling `checkNumber()` won't return since is asynchronous instead I give you some ideas to implement in a better way.

Just call the checkNumber when button click inside the check number do this instead of `return valid`

```
authRiderViewModel.response.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        Timber.d("Response: $it")
        if (it.success == true) {
            val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToOtpFragment()
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Number not registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but the livedata is giving multiple responses. I am not sure why? For example the Log statement is being printed 2 times instead of one. The first one remains false and the second one is true.

Comment: It's like the first time I entered the right number I was able to Login. I closed the app and write the wrong number this time and it showed me the Toast that Number not registered. 
I changed that number to right number and received 3 responses from live data, first one was false, and the rest two were true. Also the app crashed after that showing no errors in Logcat.

Comment: I have added question with more details if you guys want to have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73651808/how-to-make-livedata-observe-only-once-in-android-kotlin

Comment: send code of viewmodel where you declare livedata and the method onclick